# On keyword for generators of composite moduli

Tags: discrete-logarithm

The [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914254/primitive-roots-of-composite-numbers) says $n$ has a primitive root if and only if $n$ is of certain form ($n=ap^k$ where $a=1$ or $a=2$ if $p$ is an odd prime or else $a=1$ and $k\leq2$ holds).

In particular $n=pq$ or $n=pqr$ where $p,q,r$ are not all equal primes are disallowed.

Yet in [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9385/reduction-of-integer-factorization-to-discrete-logarithm-problem) discrete logarithms modulo such $n=pq$ or $n=pqr$ forms are defined and used (by this I mean there is a $g$ that generates $\phi(n)$ elements and this is used as generator).

Since generator $g$ cannot be primitive root what is the *keyword* for $g$ for these $n=pq$ or $n=pqr$ forms?

I tried [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive+roots+mod+23*59) in mathematica with no use. How to search for these generators in mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

> The link says $n$ has a primitive root if and only if $n$ is of certain form, either $n = ap^k$ where $a \in \{1, 2\}$, $p$ is an odd prime or $n \in \{2, 4\}$

This is true.

> In particular $n = pq$ or $n = prq$ where $n, q, r$ are not all equal primes are disallowed.

Other than the minor nit that $n=pq$ where $p=2$, $q$ is an odd prime does have primitive roots, the obvious question is "what do you mean is disallowed?"

A primitive root is a value $g$ where $g^k \bmod n$ can take on all values in $Z^*_n$; what the statement says is that such a $g$ will exist if $n$ is of the form listed, and no such $g$ will exist if it's not.

> Yet in here discrete logarithms modulo such $n=pq$ or $n=pqr$ forms are defined and used.

Well, yes, the problem "given $g, h$, does there exist a $k$ such that $g^k \equiv h \pmod n$ (and if it does exist, what is its value)" is well-formed, even if $n$ is not of the listed form.  Now, as there isn't a primitive root, there's no value $g$ for which such a $k$ will exist for every $h$ relatively prime to $n$; however that doesn't make this an invalid question.

> Since generator $g$ cannot be primitive root what is the keyword for $g$ for these forms?

Well, I can't think of any better term than "generator".  Any value $g$ relatively prime to $n$ will generate some subgroup; the only distinction between "primitive roots" and "everything else" is that primitive roots generate the entire group.  I suppose you might insist on a value $g$ which generates as large of a subgroup as possible (which would be, for the forms you listed, of size $\text{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ or $\text{lcm}(p-1,q-1,r-1)$), however I haven't heard of specific terminology given to elements that generate subgroups of that size.

Comment: Say $n=19*59$ I just want to know how to select a $g$ such that $g^{k}\bmod n$ contains $\phi(n)$ elements in its orbit. What about for $n=19*59*83$ or $n=19^2*53$?

Comment: @AJ.: you can't; for $n=19 \cdot 59$, the best you can do is a subgroup of size $\phi(n)/2$

Comment: why? but even then how do you get $g$ which generates maximum elements? what is the keyword? when can you get $\phi(n)$ elements?

Comment: @AJ.: why?  Well, the group structure of $Z^*_{19\cdot59}$ is isomorphic to the group $Z/18 \times Z/58 = Z/9 \times Z/2 \times Z/29 \times Z/2$.  The problem is the subgroup $Z/2 \times Z/2$; it's noncyclic, as there's no element within that subgroup that generates the entire subgroup (and hence there can't be an element that generates the entire group)

Comment: still problem remains how to get $g$ generating maximal elements? how to do it in mathematica?

Comment: @AJ.: well, one way would be to select a primitive element $g_a$ of $Z^*_{19}$, a primitive element $g_b$ of $Z^*_{59}$, and find the value $g$ with $g \equiv g_a \pmod {19}$ and $g \equiv g_b \pmod {59}$ (Chinese Remainder Thereom); that'll have maximal order.  As for how you do this in Mathematica, well, I don't know Mathematica...

Comment: and so crt is the key here. how do you show this generates maximal?

Comment: @AJ.: metaquestion: what problem are you trying to solve?  Why do you need a generator for $Z^*_n$, with $n$ composite?

Comment: I am trying to understand the basic premise in different settings. Bach and Hastaad have  papers on these but generators are not clear.