# Where is factoring if discrete logarithm is broken?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, factoring, number-theory

Assume given $g^X\equiv h\bmod p$ where $g$ is of order $\frac{\lambda(p)}2$ where $\lambda(p)$ is Carmichael Lambda function applied to prime $p$ (so $2$ is invertible in exponent) we can compute $X$ in polynomial time on an assumption $2$ is invertible in exponent (we can assume we take square roots and make the generator of order $\frac{\lambda(p)}2$ and we assume $2$ needs to be invertible in exponent).

Consider the scenario where $N=PQ$ and $P$ and $Q$ are equal bit primes and $e$ is encryption key and $d$ is decryption key satisfying $ed=1\bmod\varphi(N)$ where $\varphi(N)$ is Euler totient function applied to $N$:

> Find $r$ such that $g^r\equiv1\bmod N$ where $r$ is period of the multiplicative group modulo $N$ and $g$ generates it.

In the above two cases since we do not know $\varphi(N)$ we cannot assume $2$ is invertible in exponent.

> Is $RSA$ attackable if discrete logarithm is broken using an algorithm which makes essential utilization of $\lambda(p)$?

**PLEASE DO NOT CONNECT TO [Reduction of Integer factorization to Discrete logarithm problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9385) and please see comments on reasons. Bach utilizes blackbox notions which encompasses knowledge of $\lambda(p)$**.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reduction of Integer factorization to Discrete logarithm problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9385/reduction-of-integer-factorization-to-discrete-logarithm-problem)

Comment: @poncho no. Bach's paper gets discrete logarithm as a black box algorithm. It implicitly assumes all properties of $\lambda(p)$ can be exploited though we don't know it.

Comment: Also, a correction: "Find $r$ such that $g^r \equiv 1 \bmod N$ where $r$ is the period of the multiplicative group modulo $N$ and $g$ generates it"; actually, if $N$ is a product of two distinct odd primes, there will not be any such $g$ that generates the entire group.

Comment: @Mark I am aware of Bach's algorithm.

Comment: Yes that is why I said multiplicative group which of size much smaller than N.

Comment: I think it does not affect factoring. Bach's approach is black box assuming an implicit knowledge of group size. However is there an argument?

Comment: @1.. Isn't $\lambda(n)$ simply related to $\varphi(n)$? In particular, it looks like $\lambda(p^r) \in \{\varphi(p^r), (1/2)\varphi(p^r)\}$ for all $p, r$, so if you know $\lambda(N)$ there are at most $2^k$ choices of $\varphi(N)$, where $k$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $N$. If $N$ is a semi-prime, this is a set of size $2^2 = 4$, so you can just try all options efficiently.

Comment: @Mark: actually, for semi-primes, the relation is $\lambda(n) = \phi(n) / \gcd(p-1, q-1)$, and so there are more possibilities (especially if $\gcd(p-1, q-1)$ happens to be large).

Comment: " on an assumption 2 is invertible in exponent"; actually, Bach does not make that assumption; when Back computes $\lambda/2$, he has (with good probability) $\lambda$ even, and so division by 2 is in the integers...

Comment: I think $2$ is not invertible in exponent. He merely says pick $x$ between $0$ and $2N$ and find $g^x\bmod N$ and ask the black box to provide $x'$ having similar $g^{x'}\bmod N$ and he computes factors from $x'-x$.