# Computing p and q from private key

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis

We are given n (public modulus) where n=pq and e (encryption exponent). Then I was able to crack the private key d, using Wieners attack. So now, I have (n,e,d). My question is, is there a way to calculate p and q from this information? If so, any links and explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9145/991 $\;$

Answer (score 11):

It's actually fairly easy to factor $n$ given $e$ and $d$.  Here's the standard way to do this:

- Compute $f = ed - 1$.  What's interesting about $f$ is that $x^f \equiv 1\  (\bmod n)$ for (almost) any $x$.
- Write $f$ as $2^s g$ for an odd value $g$.
- Select a random value $a$, and compute $b = a^g \bmod n$.
- If $b = 1 $ or $-1$, then go back and select another random value of $a$
- Repeatedly (in practice, up to $s$ times):

  - compute $c = b^2 \bmod n$.
  - If $c = 1$ then the factors for $n$ are $gcd(n, b-1)$ and $gcd(n, b+1)$
  - If $c = -1$, then go back and select another random value of $a$
  - Otherwise, set $b = c$, and go through another iteration of the loop.

If you are familiar with the Miller-Rabin primality test, this will look familiar; the logic is the same (except that we use $ed-1$ rather than $n-1$ as the startign place for the exponent)

Comment: Just to clarify, so when we write $f$ as $2^s g$, do you mean $f=2^s g$? Also, is it $2^s g$ or $2^{s g}$?

Comment: @hheluilop: $f = 2^s \times g$; keep on dividing $f$ by two until you get an odd number.

Comment: There is no such value as $\gcd(n+1)$. Did you mean $\gcd(n,b+1)$?

Comment: @cpast: yes, of course

Answer (score 1):

Generally, (n,e,d) is sufficient. Using these three it is possible to decrypt, encrypt, sign and verify any message or signature.

If you still need p and q: [NIST SP 800-56B](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-56B/sp800-56B.pdf): Recommendation for Pair-Wise Key Establishment Schemes Using Integer Factorization Cryptography, Appendix C Prime Factor Recovery (Normative) contains formula for retrieving p and q, when you know (n,e,d). This formula is useful for instance to convert the private key in (n,e,d) format to CRT format.

Even a tool exists for the job: [RSA CRT/SFM Converter](http://download.cnet.com/RSA-CRT-SFM-Converter/3000-20432_4-75940236.html).

Comment: I will definitely check out the tool later. Do you know if the tool can handle 115-135 digit long integers for n and maybe 30-50 for d?

Comment: If my memory serves me right, it'll handle any usual lengths.

Comment: The algorithm in the NIST document is clear to me except for step 2. How does one calculate $r$? Is brute force the only option?

Comment: This step is fast to calculate because the other value ($2^t$) is multiple of 2. In fact, _t_ is the number of zero bits on the least significant bits of _k_. An easy way to calculate _r_ in many big number packages is to shift _k_ right _t_ steps. Either calculate the zeroes or shift one bit a time as long as the value is even.

Comment: While seeing formulas is great, sometimes I need to see it in code. Found an implementation in Python that helped me understand it better: https://github.com/truongkma/ctf-tools/blob/master/RecoverPrimeFactors.py