# Cracking RSA message with shared modulo but different e while knowing one of the private keys

Tags: rsa

How can one crack a message c_2 encoded by e_2 if one knows e_1, e_2, d_1, and both codes share common modulo n, without using factorization? 
Considering textbook RSA

Comment: Bit of an "academic" question. Knowing $e_1, d_1$ and $n$ immediately factors $n$ anyway, after which computinh $d_2$ is easy. If you can factor why is it not allowed to do it?

Comment: Because that is the assignement of it. To decrypt a message without factoring, but i have no idea as to how to proceed so i'm looking for explanation as to how to do it so i can apply it to the problem. Can you explain how do you get factors from knowing e_1 and d_1?

Comment: I explain the algorithm [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/986307/4280)

Comment: See also [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/13113/553) (with code to do it)

Comment: Just the first message you sent me made me realise how to solve it. Thank you for the hint (and later on the fuller way to factor it). I didn't really have to factor it. I can just get the phi and from that calculate inverse without factoring. Could you write an answer with those links so i can mark it s an answer?

Comment: You don't get $\phi$ but a multiple of it, if you compute $ed-1$, say. How would  you get $\phi(n)$ exactly? (maybe for small numbers it's easy to see the factorisation of $ed-1$, we can at least divide out $4$).

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yeah i skipped few steps in that sentence. I  did mean what you just say. I can get the multiple of phi and from that get the actual phi. I just skipped few steps in there.  By the way, if i may intrude some more. Is there a better way to find the actual phi other then continuosly dividing?

Comment: Factoring $n$ is pretty foolproof.

Comment: What if we considered a very large n? Wouldn't it be faster to get the phi then factoring the n?

Comment: factoring with the linked algorithm is very fast, try it. Even for 2048 bit RSA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this answer on math stackoverflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985085/attack-on-rsa-factoring-when-knowing-e-and-d/986307#986307) I explain a (probabilistic) algorithm to factor $n$ when $e$ and $d$ are both known. [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/13115/553) does the same (almost) and provides Python code to do it as well, while [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16037/553) gives some references (and even a more complicated deterministic algorithm). 
Knowing $p$ and $q$ then allows you to find $d_2$, etc.

Without this, of course you can compute $M = e_1 d_1-1$ which must be a multiple of $\phi(n)$. Inverting $e_2$ modulo $M$ will also work as a decryption exponent, most of the time. (This inverse might not exist if $M = k\phi(n)$ and $(e_2, k) \neq 1$, say.) If you'd know $\phi(n)$ exactly, you could find $p,q$ from:

$\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1) = pq - p - q +1$ so $p+q = n-\phi(n) + 1$ and so we can solve the quadratic $n=pq = p(n-\phi(n)+1-p)$ where $p$ is unknown and $n$ and $\phi(n)$ are known.

So to factor $n$ for an RSA system $(n,e)$ we can use $e$ and $d$ or $\phi(n)$.