# How to keep phi(n) secret in RSA?

Tags: rsa, public-key

As we know, RSA cryptosystem have both private key(a,p,q) and public key(b,n), by chinese remainder theorem and fermat's little theorem, we know that the importance of keep p and q secret, and from this [Why is it important that phi(n) is kept a secret, in RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5791/why-is-it-important-that-phin-is-kept-a-secret-in-rsa) post , we know $\phi$n need kept secret, but my question is, if n is a public key as encryption needed, how we keep $\phi$n as secret?

Comment: We don't tell people what it is?  The problem of finding $\phi(n)$ given $n$ is a hard problem (if $n$ is hard to factor).  So, if we give people a number that they can't factor, and we don't give them $\phi(n)$, they can't determine it on their own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do we keep $\phi(n)$ secret?

We don't tell people what it is.  The problem of finding $\phi(n)$ given $n$ is a hard problem (if $n$ is hard to factor).  So, if we give people a number that they can't factor, and we don't give them $\phi(n)$, they can't determine it on their own.