# Deletion in RSA Accumulator

Tags: rsa, accumulators

I am studying RSA Dynamic Accumulators and I have a question: why is it simpler to calculate the new accumulator value after a deletion if the secret $\phi(N)$ is known? Is possible to calculate the deletion only with the RSA modulus $N$?

Comment: The notion of RSA-based Dynamic Accumulator, and deletion for such, is not so common that you can dispense including in the question (preferably) a definition, or at least a reference. Is what you study: Michael T. Goodrich, Roberto Tamassia, Jasminka Hasic [_An Efficient Dynamic and Distributed RSA Accumulator_](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1307v1) ([arXiv:0905.1307](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1307), 2009)? Or??

Comment: I found this question (http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5791/why-is-it-important-that-phin-is-kept-a-secret-in-rsa) that explains why is important to keep the ϕ(n) secret, because with that value is simple to calculate the inverse, and then the deletion of an element.

Comment: I have a doubt: the RSA Accumulator is like an incremental hashing function?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you are talking about the typical *dynamic* RSA accumulator from *"Dynamic Accumulators and Application to Efficient Revocation of
Anonymous Credentials"*, by Camenicsh and Lysyanskaya (see [PDF here](http://cs.brown.edu/~anna/papers/camlys02.pdf)).

**First**, recall that the accumulator over *prime* elements $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ is computed in $O(n)$ time as:
\begin{align*}
A &= g^{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n}
\end{align*}

**Second**, recall that after removing some $x_i$ from the accumulator $A$, we end up with a new accumulator $A'$:
\begin{align*}
A' &= g^{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_{i-1} x_i \cdots x_n}
\end{align*}

To answer **your first question**,

> Why is it simpler to calculate the new accumulator value after a deletion if the secret $\phi(N)$ is known?

Because knowing $\phi(N)$ allows us to easily compute $A'$ from $A$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
A' &= A^{{x_i}^{-1} \bmod \phi(N)}
\end{align*}

To understand this, recall that additions and multiplications are reduced modulo $\phi(N)$ "in the exponent."
Also recall that numbers that are coprime with $\phi(N)$ (e.g., $x_i$) have multiplicative inverses $\bmod \phi(N)$ [[1]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularInverse.html).

Note that you can compute $A'$ from $A$ directly, without needing to know the other accumulated elements $x_j, j\ne i$.

To answer **your second question**,

> Is possible to calculate the deletion only with the RSA modulus $N$?

I'm assuming you mean *"calculate the new accumulator."* The answer is "yes," and you can probably see why.
Remember that, just like we can compute $A$ in $O(n)$ time, we can also compute $A'$ in $O(n)$ time (i.e., by repeated exponentiations):
\begin{align*}
A' &= ((((((g^{x_1})^{x_2}) \cdots)^{x_{i-1}})^{x_i})\cdots)^{x_n}\\
   &= g^{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_{i-1} x_i \cdots x_n}
\end{align*}

**Later edit:** As @Maeher nicely pointed out, without the trapdoor you need to *know* the other elements $x_j, j\ne i$ in order to remove $x_i$, since removing is just recomputing the accumulator without $x_i$.

If you are interested in an accumulator where you can both add and remove without knowing the other elements, you can read the elegant work by Papamanthou et al on *"Streaming Authenticated Data Structures"* from EUROCRYPT'13 ([PDF here](http://elaineshi.com/docs/streaming.pdf)). Computing new witnesses requires knowing at least part of the accumulated elements, since the construction is merely a different kind of Merkle tree. However, unlike a Merkle tree, existing witnesses can be updated given just the added/deleted elements (no need for additional sibling paths). Currently, this accumulator is based on lattices and will be less efficient.

Still, Qian et al implemented it in *"Streaming Authenticated Data Structures: Abstraction and Implementation"* at CCSW'14 ([PDF behind paywall](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2664177)).

Hope this helps 2 years later :)

Comment: In the second part of your answer, you seem to assume that all the $x_i$ are actually known. I would think that whether that is true or not heavily depends on the application.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "known." Can you give me an example of a scheme that deletes an "unknown" value? Of course $x_i$ can be a commitment to $d_i$ such as $H(d_i, r_i)$, as long as you "tweak" the hash to be a prime number.

Comment: Sorry, I should not have used $i$ as the index. I'm taking about all the other $x_j$ for $j \neq i$. It is not clear to me why you should know all of those when deleting $x_i$ and it seem that you would have to.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! Yes, in the RSA accumulator if you want to delete an element but don't know the trapdoor, you need this so-called _auxiliary information_: all the elements in the accumulator. There is a lattice-based accumulator by Papamanthou et al that doesn't have this problem. See _"Streaming Authenticated Data Structures"_ by Papamanthou, Shi, Tamassia and Yi. I will updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: How do you use the trapdoor to prove membership using just the accumulator's value?

Comment: @PedroPaixao Please consider asking a question on the site rather than asking it in a comment. That way more people are aware of the question and it keeps chatter down below the answers.

Comment: @PedroPaixao, just read my answer from above again: a membership witness $A'$ for $x_i$  w.r.t. an accumulator $A$ can be computed as $A' = A^{{x_i}^{-1} \bmod \phi(N)}$. To do this, _only_ the trapdoor $\phi(N)$, the accumulator $A$ and $x_i$ need to be known.