# Can I calculate $d$ given only RSA’s $c$, $n$ and $e$?

Tags: rsa

The question “[Calculating RSA private exponent when given public exponent and the modulus factors using extended euclid](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5889/12164)” assumes the factors are known. This got me wondering if it is possible to calculate the value of $d$ when being given only the values of $c$, $n$ and $e$… and factors remain secret.

- If it’s possible, is there an easy way to do so?
- If it’s hard/complex, what exactly makes it hard/complex?
- And in case it’s generally impossible to calculate $d$ using only those values, why?

This may be an amateurish question, but I couldn’t find the answer at Crypto.SE – so, I’m asking.

Comment: If you find a way, please tell us, this would just about break the entire internet security... (also, do you know anything else about these values or their relation?)

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Merely factorize $n$ and then compute the multiplicative inverse of $e \pmod {\phi (n)}$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm.  Note however that 'possible' does not equal 'easy'.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I was a little flippant in my comment to the first version of your question.  Your edits have made for a more substantive question, so I feel I owe you a more substantive answer.

It must be at least as hard as factoring to compute $d$ because (as I will show below) if you can compute $d$ for arbitrary $e$ then you can easily factor.  So computing $d$ is hard if and only if factoring is hard.

To see why, let's say you have an oracle that upon input of $(e,n)$ gives an output of $d$.  From this oracle we can construct an algorithm that efficiently factorizes $n$.  Recall that $d \cdot e \equiv 1 \pmod {\varphi(n)}$, or in other words $d$ and $e$ are multiplicative inverses of each other mod $\varphi(n)$.  Observe the following:

Let $^x//_y$ denote the remainder when you divide $x$ by $y$, or in other words $^x//_y = x - \lfloor \frac{x}{y}\rfloor \cdot y$.  Similarly, let the multiplicative inverse of $x$ mod $y$ be denoted by $^{x^{-1}}//\;_y$.

For any $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1>a>b$ and $gcd(a,b) = 1$,
$$(^{a^{-1}}//\;_b) = \dfrac{(^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a)\cdot b - a + 1}{a}+1 \tag{1}$$
**Proof of (1)**:
$a$ is coprime to $b$, so it has a multiplicative inverse.  The multiplicative inverse of $a$ mod $b$ is i) a natural number less than $b$ which ii) when multiplied by $a$ is congruent to 1 mod $b$.  If we multiply the right side of (1) by $a$ we get the following:
$$\left(\dfrac{(^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a)\cdot b - a + 1}{a}+1\right) \cdot a \:= (^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a)\cdot b - a + 1 + a \:\:\equiv 1 \pmod b$$
So we can complete the proof by showing that the right side of (1) is a natural number less than $b$.  First let's show that it is less than $b$ through proof by contradiction.  Assuming the opposite: $$\begin{align*}\dfrac{(^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a)\cdot b - a + 1}{a}+1 &> b \\ (^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a)\cdot b - a + 1 &> a \cdot b - a \\ (^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a)\cdot b +1 &> a \cdot b \\ 1 &> b \cdot (a - (^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a))\end{align*}$$
Recall that $b > 1$ and that $(^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a)$ is by definition smaller than $a$.  So $a - (^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a) \geq 1$, and we have our contradiction.

Second we can show that the right hand side of (1) is a natural number by showing that $(^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a)\cdot b - a + 1$ is divisible by $a$.  Note that $-b^{-1} \cdot b \equiv -1 \pmod a$, so $(^{-b^{-1}}//\:_a)\cdot b$ is one less than a multiple of $a$.  Adding one and subtracting $a$ from one less than a multiple of $a$ will result in something that is divisible by $a$. $$\tag*{QED}$$
As a consequence, if our oracle gives us $d$ given $e$, then we can use (1) to express $\varphi(n)$ in terms of $d$ and $e$:
$$\begin{align*}d = \;^{e^{-1}}//\:_{\varphi(n)} \; &= \dfrac{(^{-\varphi(n)^{-1}}//\:_e)\cdot \varphi(n) - e + 1}{e}+1 \\ (d -1) \cdot e -1 + e &= (^{-\varphi(n)^{-1}}//\:_e)\cdot \varphi(n) \\ \tag{2}\end{align*}$$
Now, select a different number, $e'$, and submit that to the oracle to get $d'$, the multiplicative inverse of $e'$.  Substituting $e'$ and $d'$ into (2) and we get $(^{-\varphi(n)^{-1}}//\:_{e'})\cdot \varphi(n)$.  If $gcd\left((^{-\varphi(n)^{-1}}//\:_{e}), (^{-\varphi(n)^{-1}}//\:_{e'})\right) = 1$, then we can then use the Euclidean Algorithm to pull out the common factor $\varphi(n)$.  We may need to repeat this process with a few different numbers submitted to the oracle to be sure we have settled on $\varphi(n)$ and not a multiple of $\varphi(n)$.  Once you know $\varphi(n)$., you can [easily find](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5791/why-is-it-important-that-phin-is-kept-a-secret-in-rsa) the prime factors of $n$.

Comment: Please note though: while finding the private exponent is equivalent to factoring the modulus, breaking the RSA problem (eg finding the e-th root modulo a composite) is not proven to be equivalent to factoring but may be easier.