# Equations modulo phi(n)

Tags: rsa

Let $n$ be an RSA modulus and assume one has the two following equations

\begin{align}
y_1 = (x+a_1)^{-1} \pmod{\varphi(n)}\\
y_2 = (x+a_2)^{-1} \pmod{\varphi(n)}
\end{align}
with known $y_1$, $y_2$, $a_1$ and $a_2$, and where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Is it possible to solve the system and recover $x$?

Comment: I'm somewhat sure that recovering $x$ in this case is equivalent to factoring $n$.

Comment: Yes, I would also say so.

Comment: I thought about this a bit more. If we can factor $n$, recovering $x$ is easy. If we can come up with $y_1,y_2,a_1,a_2$ such that the system only has one solution and we can somehow recover $x$ from such a system, we can factor $n$. This means that it suffices for a "no" answer to show how to construct the parameters for any given $n$ so that the system only admits one solution.

Comment: So you assume that $\varphi(n)$ is known but not $n?$ Otherwise $n$ can be factored, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5791/why-is-it-important-that-phin-is-kept-a-secret-in-rsa.

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear, but only $n$ is known, not $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: But then the 'equations' make no sense.

Comment: @gammatester why not? For standard RSA, one has the "equation" that $e\,d=1\text{ mod }\phi(n)$ for a known $e,n$, but for unknown $d,\phi(n)$.

Comment: The question's notation hesitates between $y_1\equiv (x+a_1)^{-1} \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ and $y_1= (x+a_1)^{-1} \bmod \varphi(n)$, with only the later bounding $y_1$ (same for $y_2)$. That's relevant because an overly large $y_1$ or $y_2$ will make factoring $n$ harder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your equations, one can write:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x + a_1 &=& \frac{1}{y_1} \mod \phi(n) \\
x + a_2 &=& \frac{1}{y_2} \mod \phi(n) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
and thus:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_1 - a_2 &=& \frac{1}{y_1} - \frac{1}{y_2} \mod \phi(n) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
which leads to:
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a_1 - a_2) y_1 y_2 - y_2 + y_1 &=& 0 \mod \phi(n) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore, one can compute $f = (a_1 - a_2) y_1 y_2 - y_2 + y_1$, and the equation above tells you that $f$ is a multiple of $\phi(n)$. At that point, you can take a random prime integer $e$ which is relatively prime to $f$ (take a random prime $e$, compute the GCD with $f$; if it is distinct from $1$, start again with a new random prime). This value $e$ will be "an RSA public exponent". You can then compute $d = e^{-1} \bmod f$, i.e. the corresponding "RSA private exponent".

Given a pair of public/private exponents $(d,e)$, one can factor the modulus $n$, using the method described [here](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_factorize_n.html) (a more formal reference is Dan Boneh's [Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem](http://www.ams.org/notices/199902/boneh.pdf)). Once $n$ is factored, you then compute $phi(n)$, at which point you can recover $x = y_1^{-1} - a_1 \bmod \phi(n)$.

Comment: Nice answer. Can $f$ be zero ?

Comment: The methods to factor $n$ from $(d,e, n)$ use $d$ and $e$ only for computing a multiple of $\phi(n)$ as $e\,d-1$. Typically we'll have $e\,d-1\gg f$ and thus we are typically better skipping the choice of $e$ and computation of $d$, and using $f$ as the desired multiple of $\phi(n)$.