# RSA - Calculating $d$ given $\varphi (N)$ and $N$

Tags: encryption, rsa, keys, decryption

From [this discussion](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5791/why-is-it-important-that-phin-is-kept-a-secret-in-rsa?newreg=316299563541477bb1ef09a3aedfc581), I know that if I know $\varphi (N)$ and $N$ (where $N=pq$, $p$ and $q$ prime), then I can very easily get $p$ and $q$.

Suppose I have the encrypted message $c$. I want to get the exponent $d$ such that $c^d \pmod N$ is the original message $m,$ *without knowing* $e.$

I know that it is theoretically possible to go through all the exponents from $1$ to $\varphi (N)$, and then see if the resulting message makes sense. But since I know $p$ and $q$ and $N$, I think there should be a better way than brute force.

I don't know if trying to factor $\varphi (N)$ is that much easier than trying to factor $N$? That means that even though not all numbers between $1$ and $\varphi (N)$ will have inverses (since they will not all be relatively prime to $\varphi (N)$) I won't know based on the information I have.

Is there a better approach to breaking the encryption?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: What information do you have about $m$?  If your knowledge is uniformly distributed among all possible values, then there is no way to distinguish one candidate value of $d$ from another.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I don't know anything about $m$. Is there a way to narrow down the choices for $d$ given that I can find $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @Jess No.  From the information you have, every one of the $\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ possible values for $(e,d)$ is equiprobable.  If you narrowed $m$ down to a single possibility, you could compute $\log_c m$ (modulo $p$ and $q$ independently to accelerate it, and then combined to find it modulo $n$ with CRT).  Similarly, if you knew a nonuniform probability distribution for $m$ that would induce a nonuniform probability distribution on $d = \log_c m$.  But if as far as you know $m$ and $e$ are both uniformly distributed, then so is $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem summary: in textbook RSA, it is given $N$, $\phi(N)$, and a ciphertext $c$. It is wanted the plaintext message $m$ and a private exponent $d$.

If $e$ or $m$ was random, that would be infeasible. But usually, $e$ is small thus guessable, and $m$ is highly redundant/recognizable. Thus we can try to compute
$$\begin{align}
d_e&=e^{-1}\bmod\phi(N)\\
m_e&=c^{d_e}\bmod N
\end{align}$$
for various small values of $e$ coprime with $\phi(N)$, and see which $m_e$ makes sense. Computing an $m_e$ has moderate cost, comparable to a normal decryption.

I'd first try $e=F_i=2^{(2^i)}+1$ for $i\in[0,4]$ (the [Fermat primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number), with $F_4=65537$ and $F_0=3$ very common). Then we can try (other) small odd integer $e>1$, including the [popular $43$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30825/555). I've also seen $e=2^{F_i}+1$ ($i\le3$), apparently due to a coding error.

If we find that a candidate $e$ is not coprime with $\phi(n)$, we can increase it by $2$ until it does, because some key generators do just that.